# Count number of k-cycles in complete directed graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is there a closed formula to solve the total number of cycles of any length in a complete and directed graph (without loops)?

Comment: Why do you require your graph to be directed? Are you looking for a number of *oriented* cycles? If orientation is not important, then please look at: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35453/finding-all-cycles-of-a-certain-length-in-a-graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the graph is complete, and assuming that your definition of "cycle" forbids revisiting vertices (except to close the cycle), we can simply select $k$ nodes to form a cycle without further restriction. No loops means that the minimum cycle length is $2$. Each cycle will be counted $k$ times, however, once for each node along its length. So there are $\frac{v!}{(v-k)!k}$ $k$-cycles in a completed directed graph of $v$ vertices, $k>1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess this is exactly what was looking for. I looked up several textbooks, but maybe I overlooked it... Do you know maybe a quotable source?

Comment: @Peanut it really just follows from your definitions - to find the cycles, pick one of the $v$ nodes to start, pick one of the $(v-1)$ remaining nodes for the next step, etc. until you have $k$ nodes, then step back to your starting node. $v \times (v-1) \times (v-2) \times \cdots (v-(k-1)) = \frac{v!}{(v-k)!}$

Comment: @Joffan - it looks like your formula gives too many cycles. Set $v = 3, k = 3$ for example. There is only one 3-cycle in a complete directed graph with 3 vertices.

Comment: Thanks @HEKTO . Each cycle will be counted k times for the nodes participating, I will update. However there are two cycles in the complete 3-digraph, one in each direction.